# How can I create a polygon(filled polygon) from a single pixel stored in a hdf file(MODIS)?

Tags: modis, hdf, modis-reprojection-tool

I'm working with MODIS data to get EVI. I'm following [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198239/how-to-tranform-modis-tiles-into-lat-long) to get the required values of EVI. The hdf file has 4800x4800 rows/columns (250m). I can get the X,Y pixel coordinates and the corresponding value. Now I'm trying to get this pixel as a polygon so that I can merge all the polygons with the same value. But I'm not sure how to get it.

As per my understanding, the X,Y pixel values are the coordinates of bottom right corner of the pixel. How can I create a polygon out of it ?